# how to make chartjs columns smaller in width for bar chart?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a chartJS chart and I don't understand how to make the columns smaller in width when there are few of them

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `barPercentage` for that:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    barPercentage: 0.4,
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```